# Suddenly getting: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Ive been able to save an output image fine using the same code as I'm using now, however, as I've been updating my application it appears that the code to save my image has now broke in some way.

If I put it so that the file saves after 'combining' to create the output it works fine, and I have resorted to using this to ensure the application is actually working properly (which it is). I did want the user of the application to be able to control the filenames so that nothing is overwritten and as I say, it worked fine previously.

The code I'm using to save the image is here:

```
private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Save as...","");
        save(fileName, combinedImage);
    }
```

---

```
public static void save(String fileName, BufferedImage combinedImage) {
            try {
            File outputfile = new File(fileName+".png");
            ImageIO.write(combinedImage, "png", outputfile);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File successfully saved as: "+outputfile);
            System.out.println("File saved successfully: "+outputfile);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Save Image Error", "Save Image Error", WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
```

Where `combinedImage` is the output I wish to save as a PNG image.

---

The full error message is also here:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
    at grey2RGB.save(grey2RGB.java:808)
    at grey2RGB.saveButtonActionPerformed(grey2RGB.java:721)
    at grey2RGB.access$2100(grey2RGB.java:29)
    at grey2RGB$22.actionPerformed(grey2RGB.java:440)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Line 808 is

```
ImageIO.write(combinedImage, "png", outputfile);
```

Line 721 is

```
save(fileName, combinedImage);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check what is there `at grey2RGB$22.actionPerformed(grey2RGB.java:440)`

Comment: Well, as the message says, your image is null. So the error is in the code that creates the image and passes it to this method.

Comment: Try running your code through your debugger and make sure that `combinedImage` isn't null by the time you save. Make sure that any edits that you made to your code before it stopped working didn't accidentally set `combinedImage` to null or forget set it to an actual vale. It could also help us if you showed us the parts of your program that deal with changing your image.

Comment: Check your image Isnt actually null. also you should use a [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: So by printing `combinedImage` when I press the save button shows that it is `null` but im not entirely sure why. With `combinedImage` set as `static` its still `null` too...

Comment: Yes, we've already told you that it's null, that's not news to us. What we need to see in order to help you is your code that sets it to something that isn't null. If there isn't any, there's your problem.

Comment: But theres no reason for it to be null, I can see `combinedImage` on my screen when I run the application. Something is setting it to null or its not being passed correctly to the save method(s) but I dont know why or how. I think the issue is not being able to pass it to the save button as im using Netbeans and it makes the auto-generated GUI code read-only so you cant edit the parameters but that seems stupid?

Answer (score 0):

Often this sort of problem is caused by there being more than one variable named `combinedImage` (and using the wrong one). For example, check:

- that you do not have multiple variables called `combinedImage` in different places
- that if `combinedImage` is a member variable, that you are using it from the same instance of object wherever you expect to do so

If that doesn't help, then get out your debugger and trace the code.